# nginx doesn't transform matched uri to upstream

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I want to configure a reverse proxy for access foreign web site, but when I configure the proxy_pass use new uri, nginx adds the matched uri to upstream which response 404

my confirgure is:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server test.com;
    location / {
        $url $arg_url;

        proxy_pass $url;
        proxy_set_header Host      $host; 
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP    $remote_addr; 
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;  
    }
}
```

my request url is: http://test.com?url=http://www.example.com/path/article.html
then the backend received the request is http://www.example.com/path/article.html/, this responds 404.

can you help me, I don't want the matched uri '/' to be added to the end of proxy_pass address, thanks.

Comment: I don't think that's due to this nginx excerpt but to your browser or a redirection in the backend part. Btw `set $url $arg_url` is useless, use `$arg_url` directly.

Comment: thanks for your help, I have solved it, just delete proxy_set_header Host      $host; and it works fine, maybe nginx doesn't have this fault. additionly, set $url $arg_url; which is used to filter the args, such as url params